# Android Studio App Restarts when pushed to Background, how to save current fragment?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm making an app in Android Studio using Java. Whenever the app is running, but then pushed to the background (hitting the home button for example) and then returned to the foreground, the app restarts, losing the "spot" in the app. I'm using fragments and a navigation graph to control going between. I've tried using onStop and onSaveInstance, but haven't been able to figure out how to use them to save the actual fragment the user was on rather than just data from the fragment. I've tried implementing a ViewModel, but again, can't figure out how to get the fragment the user was on back after the restart. I understand that the phone automatically closes some apps when they go into the background to save memory, but I want the user to still be able to return to the state it was in when they left. What is the best approach to this?

Comment: I think using sharedPreferences will help you to achieve both the scenario. First you have to store the user state data and app state when app is going to background. And when you app is on foreground then get the state data form SharedPreference and perform your actions accordingly. I hope this will help you.